# If value in cell look in next column and replace it VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am using this function to replace values :

```
Public Function replaceWord(t As String)
   For Each c In Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
   t = Replace(t, c.Value, c.Offset(0, 1).Value)
   Next
   replaceWord = t
End Function
```

Like this:

[image]

So the function work like this, it checks if values in column `C` are also in column `A`. If found it, is going to replace it with values in column `B`.

I would like to adjust this function so only if exact values in column `A` are found then do the replacement. Like in the picture, where text in column `C` becomes text in column `E`, so `a b abaaa`, as the value `abaaa` is not present in column `A`.

At the present the function does this, which is wrong, as value `abaaa` should not be replaced it:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried, replacing using the text plus a space as the find? then it will miss abaaa if it's the end of the text.

Comment: thanks for this! I tried to put spaces, then it works fine but it does not work if it has to replace the first part of the value, for example in this case is not going to replace "aaa" at the beginning of the cell, as is going to do this: "aaa b abaaa". Is there a way to add a space in the function for each "t", so something like this: " " & t & " ", so the t text that  has to be replaced is going to have a space in the front?

Comment: do   string & iif(len(c.value)=len(c.Offset(0, 1).Value),"",chr(32))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit
Public Function replaceWord(t As String, referenceRng As Range, colOffset as long)
    Dim found As Range
    Dim strng As Variant

    replaceWord = ""
    For Each strng In Split(t, " ")
        Set found = referenceRng.Find(what:=strng, lookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
        If found Is Nothing Then
            replaceWord = replaceWord & strng & " "
        Else
            replaceWord = replaceWord & found.Offset(, colOffset ).Value & " "
        End If
    Next strng
    replaceWord = Trim(replaceWord)
End Function
```

to be called like

```
Sub test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetTest") '<== change it as per your needs
        .Range("E1") = replaceWord(.Range("C1").Value, .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues), 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great!! is exactly what I need. Is there just another way not to write the result in cell("E1"), but instead a subroutine to use a function, so to include all in the first function, replaceWord?

Comment: it surely is exploitable in many different ways, please explain in more details what you mean by _"subroutine to use a function, so to include all in the first function, replaceWord"_ . Finally if my answer fulfilled your original question, please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: let's say in the column C I have many values (in C1, C2, C3...) so all my values in column C are called "t", like you did in your function. Now I would like to have just a function that applies to the variable "t", so for example I can only use the replaceWord funtion across different cells. so i can write in one cell =replaceWord(C2) and this function is going to to all the subroutine.

Comment: just apply the function to t, without exporting in E1. Something like this: {Function replaceWord(t as String)

t = replaceWord(t)

Next
End Function}

Comment: `replaceWord` is already a function you can type in any cell and exploit it. For instance type in "E1" _"=replaceWord(C1,$A$1:$A$100,1)"_ and see there appears the "replaced" word of whatever was in cell "C1" being "dictionary" in cells "$A$1:$A$100" and its corresponding "translation" one (1) column to the right. However If both "dictionary" and its "translation" columns are fixed, you can hard code them in the function and have it accept only one parameter, which is the string to "translate"